# An <ul><li> list which has display:none; on itself and all children, still adds a 3px padding to the parent <li>

Tags: html, css, parsing, whitespace

So, I've got a standard nested **ul li** list inside another **li**, such as this:

```
<li><a href="#">Link</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

The **ul** and all it's children have **display:block;** but still, there is a 3px padding on the right of the parent **li**.

The issue is simplest presented by just looking at it yourself:
[link](http://zarkokuvalja.com/dropbox/stack/)

look at the third link

However, this issue dissapears when all whitespace is removed from the HTML above in between the closing of the topmost anchor tag and the lowermost closing **li** tag.

This seems to be happening in Chrome and Firefox, and I hadn't tested further but instead wanted to ask around here to see if this is some common knowledge that I am lacking or is this a proper bug.

Comment: Well yes, that is one fix, but display:inline on <li> should be enough, no?
In any case, the issue is that whitespace is being rendered where (I think) it shouldn't be. Or should it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a `display: inline;` on your `li`s the whitespaces/linebreaks after the `<a>` element in your third `li` get displayed as a single whitespace.

If you `float` the `li`s and leave the default `display: block;` you get the same horizontal list without this effect.

Comment: Ah, inline - it kind of explains itself actually. 
Thanks to you guys and the fellow that commented above.